# How to change my view file to get a appropriate output?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a controller like this :

```
def mytask = {
        def user = User.findByLogin(params.id)
        def mywork = user.schedules.daySchedules
        [ mywork : mywork ]
    }
```

Where I'm trying to find all the tasks assigned to a particular `user`. I have a corresponding view file :

```
<g:each in="${mywork}" var="tasks">
                <div id = "todayswork">
                        ${tasks.task}               
                    </div>
                    <div id ="Dates">
                        ${tasks.startTime}-
                        ${tasks.endTime}
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
            </g:each>
```

Logic works fine, I'm getting the output as I wanted. For example, if I go to `http://localhost:8080/scheduleTest/daySchedule/mytask/anto` my browser showing all the task for the user `anto`. But there is a problem in rendering it.

**I'm getting the output as :**

[image]

**But I need the output something like this one:**

[image]

How change my view file to get the appropriate output.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from your examples, but my guess is you need to be looping over the `tasks` item, which appears to be a List in a List.

This means change this:

```
<g:each in="${mywork}" var="tasks">
```

to this

```
<g:each in="${mywork[0]}" var="tasks">
// or
<g:each in="${mywork.tasks}" var="tasks">
```

Again, I'm not exactly sure where the problem is occurring, but one of those will fix it.

The reason you are getting the output is that Groovy will automatically perform a property expansion on a list if the property is not defined on that list.  Example:

```
use(org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.TimeCategory) {
    def d1 = 5.minutes.ago
    def d2 = 1.week.from.now
    assert [d1, d2].time == [d1.time, d2.time]
}
```

It's the same thing as writing `list*.property`, and returns a new list containing each `property` on the original items.

Comment: yup it works. Even I found that it returning a list of list by writing a integration test and making it fail. Thanks for giving the example with `use` and explaining it.